# How could you increase the screen brightness in Android using a seek bar?

Tags: android, seekbar, brightness, scroller

I would like to increase the brightness of the screen using a seek bar within my Android application, but I'm not sure how to do this.  How can I add this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using this you can set the screen brightness:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.screenBrightness = 100 / 100.0f;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Now, as you want to implement progress bar like control, i would suggest you to implement SeekBar, so using this you can easily increase/decrease based on tracking value of seekbar.

[Here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/02/change-android-screen-brightness.html) is the full example implemented using the SeekBar.

Comment: But the screen brightness bar disappear. How not let it disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Use this to change the brightness (system-wide)

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
 int brightness = Settings.System.getInt(cr,Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);            
 Settings.System.putInt(cr, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
 WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
 lp.screenBrightness = brightness / 255.0f;
 getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

You may use [this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/SeekBar1.html) and call the above code in `onProgressChanged()`. Default values of `progress` range from 0 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the screen brightness using the WindowManager.LayoutParams.
Get the LayoutParams using `getWindow().getAttributes()` then set the field `screenBrightness` to a number between 0 to 1 (0 dark, 1 bright) and then call `getWindow().setAttributes()` with your modified LayoutParams object.