# Android - Change LED brightness with seekbar

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I made a flashlight app that turns on the led light from the camera with a button. I want to be able to change the brightness of the led light with a seekbar if possible.

here is the code from my button if this will help:

```
public class FlashLightActivity extends Activity {


private boolean isLighOn = false;
private Camera camera;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFlashlight);
    Context context = this;
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

    if (!pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Log.e("err", "Device has no camera!");
        return;
    }

    camera = Camera.open();
    final Parameters p = camera.getParameters();

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (isLighOn) {
                Log.i("info", "torch is turn off!");
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isLighOn = false;
            } else {
                Log.i("info", "torch is turn on!");
                p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(p);
                camera.startPreview();
                isLighOn = true;
            }
        }
    });
    }
 }
```

Comment: i think your problem solve.any query ?

Comment: yes, this is not working for the camera led, this is for the screen led light.

Answer (score 1):

check the example given at [Increase/Decrease Brightness of Image](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/image-processing-brightness-over-image/)

and do as shown below on seekbar progress changes

```
 int brightness;
 SeekBar seekbarbrightness=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
 seekbarbrightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) {

             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             brightness=progress;
             Bitmap bitmap=doBrightness(originalbitmap,brightness);
             imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
         }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see from my own searching (I also want to control the brightness of the Camera LED for a different application) it is only possible to use the Camera interface to turn the LED off or on using Torch mode.

Now, it is also possible to write a simulated PWM (Pulse Width Modulation) at the Java level to toggle between TORCH_MODE and OFF. But my tests doing this created too much flicker.

I then also tried to look at a similar approach at the Native level using NDK but it seems that the only interface to the Camera (and LED) is via the Java layer.

#### Update 2013-10-05

Here follows the Java code for PWM control of the Camera LED. It works, but the flicker makes it generally unusable. There are probably more optimisations that can be added, but not sure if they would have a significant impact on the flickering.

#### Update 2013-12-15

From the feedback by Class Stacker I have removed the unattainable Thread priority and also improved the PWM delays to make sole use of the Thread.sleep functions. Testing has shown a slight improvement, but the flicker is still present. Note that the sleep values could be reduced, but the camera API calls take a considerable time to return such that reducing the PWM sleeps doesn't have any impact on the flickering.

```
package com.whimsicalotter.ledpwmexample;

import java.util.List;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.util.Log;

public class LedPwmController {

private static String TAG = "LedPwmController";

private Camera m_camera = null;
private boolean m_torchSupported = false;

private LedPwmThread m_ledPwmThread = null;

private final int m_pwmMax = 10;
private int m_pwmValue = m_pwmMax;


public void init() {
    initCamera();

    // Start the thread
    m_ledPwmThread = new LedPwmThread();
    m_ledPwmThread.setRunning(true);
    m_ledPwmThread.start();
}

public void shutdown() {
    // Join the thread
    boolean retry = true;

    if (m_ledPwmThread != null) {
        m_ledPwmThread.setRunning(false);

        while (retry) {
            try {
                m_ledPwmThread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }

    destroyCamera();
}

/**
 * Set the LED brightness 0.0f to 1.0f.
 * @param brightness
 */
public void setLedBrightness(float brightness) {
    if( brightness < 0.0f ) brightness = 0.0f;
    if( brightness > 1.0f ) brightness = 1.0f;

    // Now convert to integer
    m_pwmValue = (int) Math.floor((brightness * (float)m_pwmMax));

    Log.i(TAG, "LED Brightness set:" + brightness + " == " + m_pwmValue);
}



private void initCamera() {
    if( m_camera == null ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Opening Camera...");

        m_camera = Camera.open();

        m_torchSupported = isTorchSupported();

        Log.i(TAG, "Camera is open. Torch Supported = " + m_torchSupported);
    }
}

private void destroyCamera() {
    // switch off led
    ledOff();

    if( m_camera != null ) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Releasing Camera...");
        m_camera.release();
        m_camera = null;
    }
}

private boolean isTorchSupported() {
    if( m_camera != null ) {
        Parameters params = m_camera.getParameters();
        List<String> flashmodes = params.getSupportedFlashModes();
        if( flashmodes == null ) {
            return false;
        }

        return flashmodes.contains( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH );
    }

    return false;
}

private void ledOn() {
    if( !m_torchSupported ) {
        return;
    }

    if( m_camera != null ) {
        Parameters params = m_camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH );
        m_camera.setParameters(params);
    }
}

private void ledOff() {
    if( !m_torchSupported ) {
        return;
    }

    if( m_camera != null ) {
        Parameters params = m_camera.getParameters();
        params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF );
        m_camera.setParameters(params);
    }
}


private class LedPwmThread extends Thread {

    private boolean m_running = false;

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        m_running = running;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if( m_camera != null && m_torchSupported ) {
            Parameters params = m_camera.getParameters();

            while( m_running ) {

                //ledOn();
                if( m_pwmValue > 0 ) {
                    params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    m_camera.setParameters(params);


                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10*m_pwmValue,0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }

                //ledOff();
                if( m_pwmValue < m_pwmMax ) {
                    params.setFlashMode( Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF );
                    m_camera.setParameters(params);


                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10*(m_pwmMax-m_pwmValue),0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }   
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "Optimisations being possible" is a nice way to describe the many problems which your code has, such as trying to set a non-achievable thread priority and not simply using two sleep() calls with durations calculated according to the PWM duty cycle. However, your finding is still valid -- the usually low priority and probably even the huge API overhead (only one parameter is changed, but most likely all will be processed) renders this approach unfeasible in general.

Comment: @ClassStacker : thanks ;). Yes, the PWM could simply make use of two sleep calls. And the Thread priority setting was something of a shot in the dark to see if there was any effect. It's a pity that the LED isn't accessible by the NDK level C.

Answer (score 0):

i give full example for that your question:

MainActivity :-

```
public class AndroidScreenBrightness extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     SeekBar BackLightControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.backlightcontrol);
     final TextView BackLightSetting = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.backlightsetting);

     BackLightControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  float BackLightValue = (float)arg1/100;
  BackLightSetting.setText(String.valueOf(BackLightValue));

  WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
  layoutParams.screenBrightness = BackLightValue;
  getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);


 }

 @Override
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }});
 }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   >
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/hello"
   />
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Set BackLight of the App"
   />
<SeekBar
   android:id="@+id/backlightcontrol"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="10px"
   android:max="100"
   android:progress="50"
   />
<TextView 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:id="@+id/backlightsetting"
   android:text="0.50"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: but why do the first 2 textviews now have a id?

Comment: actully first 2 textview use only for space in designing not use in programically so not given id.

Comment: ok, now this is for the screen brightness led. I was looking for something for the camera led light. You know the light used for the camera flash.

Comment: is it possible for me to implement this for the flashlight by declaring and changing a few variables?

Answer (score 0):

It's simple code is as follows in onCreate methord:

```
SeekBar brightnesSseeker;   
brightnesSseeker = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.brightnesSseeker);

    brightnesSseeker
            .setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // Nothing handled here
                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // Nothing handled here
                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                        int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    // Set the minimal brightness level
                    // if seek bar is 20 or any value below
                    if (progress <= 20) {
                        // Set the brightness to 20
                        screenBrightness(20);
                    } else {
                        // Set brightness variable based on the progress bar
                        screenBrightness(progress);
                    }
                    stobeVariable=progress*10;
                }
            });
```

write this function below in class:

```
private void screenBrightness(double newBrightnessValue) {
    /*
     * WindowManager.LayoutParams settings = getWindow().getAttributes();
     * settings.screenBrightness = newBrightnessValue;
     * getWindow().setAttributes(settings);
     */
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
    float newBrightness = (float) newBrightnessValue;
    lp.screenBrightness = newBrightness / (float) 255;
    getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
}
```

You can see this link too:
Here's [a Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845458/how-could-you-increase-the-screen-brightness-in-android-using-a-seek-bar)